# How to Package APK without wrong architecture libfreetype.so

Tags: python, buildozer

I am new to buildozer, but I have what should be a simple question:
When I add "freetype-py" to my requirements, it installs with a libfreetype.so for x86-64 for some reason (this may be pip default behavior). After installing my APK, the program fails to run because of the wrong libfreetype.so architecture. Going into adb shell and simply removing the offending file causes my program to work completely (libfreetype.so is correctly installed by another freetype requirement).

How do I either tell buildozer to not package this file that comes with freetype-py, or update the freetype-py recipe to pass the --no-binary flag to "pip install freetype-py" to avoid downloading a problematic file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the conclusion is that we had to build a recipe for freetype-py. We've done it and they've accepted it upstream, so this shouldn't be a problem moving forward.